# R data.table read in specific cells by row condition from a .csv or text file

Tags: r, import, data.table, conditional-statements

I am developing a small shiny app that reads in and processes raw ELISA data.  The data is in this format:

```
1560200  Version 1.06                                                       
15/09/2021 16:22                                                    
Serial Number:  19103026                                                
Protocol Name:  euroimmune elisa                                                
Read:   Normal   00:05 Shake                                            
Blanks: None                                                
                                                    
450     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
    A   0.612   0.081   0.638   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    B   1.886   0.082   0.502   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    C   0.064   1.297   0.072   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    D   2.343   0.571   0.069   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    E   0.082   0.289   0.621   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    F   0.265   3.648   0.224   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    G   1.063   0.114   2.411   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    H   0.942   0.685   0.09    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                                                    
630     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
    A   0.037   0.035   0.034   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    B   0.037   0.035   0.036   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    C   0.041   0.039   0.035   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    D   0.037   0.033   0.037   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    E   0.036   0.033   0.037   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    F   0.035   0.041   0.037   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    G   0.036   0.034   0.041   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    H   0.037   0.035   0.036   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                                                    
Delta       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
    A   0.575   0.046   0.604   0.575   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    B   1.849   0.047   0.466   1.849   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    C   0.023   1.258   0.037   0.023   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    D   2.306   0.538   0.032   2.306   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    E   0.046   0.256   0.584   0.046   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    F   0.23    3.607   0.187   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    G   1.027   0.08    2.37    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    H   0.905   0.65    0.054   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Of note there is no column name for the row headers and the rest of the column headers are just numbered 1 to 12.  If a cell has a result, there will be a numeric value in it - otherwise blank cells have the value 0.

I have some code that specifies exactly which cells to read the data from (by cell reference) with the output of the ELISA reader I normally use:

```
# Import raw ELISA data from .csv:
elisa_raw <- fread(file = params$resultats, 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE, # read in strings as characters
                     skip = 27, # number of rows to skip
                     select = c(2:14), # which columns to select
                     header = TRUE, # use the first row of the selected data as column names
                     dec = ".", # specify the decimal separator (comma or period)
                     colClasses = list(character = 2, numeric = 3:14)) # predefine column types
```

This works fine, however I want to upgrade the code to deal with more general situations - for example if the software on my ELISA reader is updated, the number of lines to skip might change.  If I want my app to be usable for people that have a different model of ELISA reader, there will definitely be a different number of lines or columns to skip.

The one thing that stays the same in all these scenarios is the structure of the data: it remains as above, with 8 rows and 13 columns (the first one being the row headers), where rows are named A - H and columns are named 1 - 12.  The column containing the row headers usually has no name.

I wanted to see if there was a way I could conditionally select the data cells to import from  using this structure.  I tried `grep -E` with fread as below and described in [this post](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3566384/5-handy-options-in-r-datatables-fread.html):

```
elisa_raw <- fread(cmd = "grep -E 'A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H' TF_210915_IPB.txt")
```

I thought this would import all the rows where the first value of the row was either A or B or C etc.  However this gives me an error:

```
> elisa_raw <- fread(cmd = "grep -E 'A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H' TF_210915_IPB.txt")
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: In (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
  '(grep -E 'A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H' TF_210915_IPB.txt) > C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeki6Rv\file4010600782e' execution failed with error code 255
2: In fread(cmd = "grep -E 'A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H' TF_210915_IPB.txt") :
  File 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeki6Rv\file4010600782e' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

Unlike the original post I could not specify the column names, because there is none for the row headers.  I´m working on a PC with windows 10; I understood that `grep -E` was the correct command in this context but now not so sure given the error message.

How can I make this work or is there another way to approach this?

**Edit:**

In order to demonstrate the kind of files I am importing and how they vary, I have provided the dput of two different examples of raw ELISA files below.  They were imported into r without any specifications to preserve their structure as follows:

```
# Example file 1: .csv from a Biotek reader
biotek <- fread(file = "Biotek_21091501.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = c(""))

# Example file 2: .txt from a ThermoFisher Scientific reader
tfs <- fread(file = "TF_21091501.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = c(""))
```

These example files can be recreated by using the dput below to recreate the objects in R and then exporting as .csv and .txt, respectively (without column headers or row names).

Note that one of the two files actually has three data structures which meet my criteria, and I only need the third one (entitled delta).  At the moment though I don´t mind any solutions that bring back all three, because I can subset them afterwards.

```
# Example data from Biotek ELISA reader 1:
> dput(biotek)
structure(list(V1 = c("1560200  Version 1.06", "15/09/2021 16:22", 
"Serial Number:", "Protocol Name:", "Read:", "Blanks:", "", "450", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "630", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "Delta", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), V2 = c("", 
"", "19103026", "euroimmune elisa", "Normal", "None", "", "", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "", "", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "", "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"), V3 = c("", "", "", "", "00:05 Shake", "", "", "1", 
"0.612", "1.886", "0.064", "2.343", "0.082", "0.265", "1.063", 
"0.942", "", "1", "0.037", "0.037", "0.041", "0.037", "0.036", 
"0.035", "0.036", "0.037", "", "1", "0.575", "1.849", "0.023", 
"2.306", "0.046", "0.23", "1.027", "0.905"), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 0.081, 0.082, 1.297, 0.571, 0.289, 3.648, 
0.114, 0.685, NA, 2, 0.035, 0.035, 0.039, 0.033, 0.033, 0.041, 
0.034, 0.035, NA, 2, 0.046, 0.047, 1.258, 0.538, 0.256, 3.607, 
0.08, 0.65), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 0.638, 0.502, 
0.072, 0.069, 0.621, 0.224, 2.411, 0.09, NA, 3, 0.034, 0.036, 
0.035, 0.037, 0.037, 0.037, 0.041, 0.036, NA, 3, 0.604, 0.466, 
0.037, 0.032, 0.584, 0.187, 2.37, 0.054), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 4, 0.575, 1.849, 0.023, 2.306, 0.046, 0, 0, 0
), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), V10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V11 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 9L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), V12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), V14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002a5ddbf1ef0>)

# Example data from ThermoFisher Scientific ELISA reader 2:
> dput(tfs)
structure(list(V1 = c("Protocole:", "Format de plaque:", "", 
"Absorbances     Filtre 1: 450nm", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), V2 = c("Demo3 15.09.2021 17:11:54", 
"96 puits", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "0.456", 
"1.337", "0.065", "1.577", "0.123", "0.33", "1.094", "0.291"), 
    V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    0.134, 0.116, 1.112, 0.29, 0.209, 2.915, 0.353, 0.719), V4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 0.513, 0.342, 
    0.109, 0.112, 0.562, 0.238, 2.224, 0.15), V5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V7 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    V11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), V13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002a5ddbf1ef0>)
```

Comment: Please show the input.  `elisa_raw` is not the input.

Comment: Concur: this question is good for everything (sample data, code attempted) except the fact that it does not include the information we really need to better inform an answer.

Comment: Does the [`ELISAtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ELISAtools/index.html) package do any of this for you?

Comment: @r2evans I have edited my post to include two dputs of examples.  I have not come across the ELISAtools package before, will have a look at it.

Comment: You need help reading in the data from raw files, right? It doesn't help much to look at post-imported data to help with pre-import issues. Best way? Perhaps include the first 20 lines from the raw file (as G.Grothendieck first suggested).

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand your suggestion.  I can import the entire .csv without problems, but it has a lot of header information which I don´t need in my actual results table (i.e. it is not in tidy data format).   If you dput and then write.csv you will have replicates of the two different file types I am trying to import with the same code. If there is another way to share the input files can you please give example code?  dput is the only command I know for this...

Comment: Also just to mention that I could also import the entire raw files "as is" and then work on some non-file specific way of subsetting them to get only the data that I want into the table, as the input files are quite small.  I just thought if there was a way to only import what I need that would be better as I won´t be cluttering up my environment with unnecessary data objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237288/discussion-between-amy-m-and-r2evans).

Comment: [1/2] *"import the entire .csv without problems"* is not demonstrated by your question and by the format of your `dput` output: you have many lines of metadata in your frame. Your current code with hard-coded line counts and such works, but you said you want a more general solution. We cannot help you with this general solution if we don't know exactly how the data looks *before* you use this hard-coded response.

Comment: [2/2] Also, how do you expect it to vary? What variables/portions do you need to generalize? Lastly, you ask for a *"way of subsetting them to get only data data"* ... but you don't show anything pre-import, just the results of a brute-force import.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, the data varies only in the position of the block of cells that I want to import - that´s basically it.  So the number of rows and columns to skip varies.  I´m still not sure I understand why recreating the two examples with dput and then exporting them as .csv would not show you what the original .csv files I am importing look like - baring the row and column names introduced by R, on my set-up they are exactly the same.  The two examples are from different ELISA readers and illustrate exactly the type of variation I am trying to handle.

Comment: P.s. I should mention that the code I used to import the two examples represented in dput is not included in my post - I literally just imported the entire file without specifying any rows or columns.  Sorry if this is what was causing the confusion - will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: We need to see the raw file before the import. Just paste it into your post as text, not dput. Also, did you try to use ELISAtools as suggested above?

Comment: Edited to include a paste of one of the raw files directly from .csv - I didn´t do that at first because it is very long, but I hope the structure is clearer now.  I have not yet tried using ELISAtools as my internet is too slow to install it or view the vignette at the moment.

Comment: @zx8754 I have now had a quick look at ELISAtools but it does not seem to cater for import of different ELISA reader file types (only one make is mentioned in the vignette).

Comment: So one file can contain multiple 96 well plates? And A1 well can start at any row/column, right?

Comment: I think there will be already packages that read certain plate format files, quick google says plater, platetools, etc. I would start trying out those specialised packages, instead of trying to re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237324/discussion-between-amy-m-and-zx8754).